# How do I stop my cables from getting tangled inside my box?

Tags: storage, cables

I've a box of different cables, but they're always get tangled.

**Any ideas how to store bunch of cables without getting tangled?**

Comment: Why has this received a down vote? I've got countless boxes filled with even more cables and it works out easier and less time consuming to go buy a new cable rather than try and tackle the mess of the wire box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have some empty tubes, you can store each cable inside the tube by keeping them separated.

In example you can use inner cardboard tube from kitchen roll, wrapping paper or toilet paper.

[image: Sick of having a box full of tangled cords]

<sup>Image credits: [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/TP-Roll-Organizer-Box-instructable/)</sup>

See more at:

- [TP Roll Organizer Box instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/TP-Roll-Organizer-Box-instructable/) at instructables

Answer (score 2):

A nice method from kenorb, however I personally never keep my toilet roll tubes laying about the place and never think to save them for anything in particular - poor planning on my part I know...

A method I have tried before when moving electronic goods around (i.e. when moving out to University or something) I have simply put the individual cables in a nice loop and sellotape around the middle - keeps them from running free around the place and helps to prevent tangling. Much like how the cables come in the packet when you first get them - must be done for a reason right?[image]
The cable in the middle is what I am trying to describe...

I also used large sticky labels which I could wrap around some of the thinner wires (charging cables and such) and I could then write what electronic item they went to, which made unpacking and reassembling much easier. Using this idea string with tags attached would also be a neat method but you might just get the string caught up instead of the wires so something to think about!

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this technique for years:

1. Bring the 2 ends of the cable/cord together.
2. Shove the "middle" of the cord (everything but the ends) into a plastic bag that has a zipper (like Zip-Loc brand).  Leave the ends of the cords sticking out.
3. Zip the bag snugly around the 2 ends.

It works excellently. You can label the bag too, so you can tell what cord belongs to what. [I even made a video about this trick.](http://youtu.be/iV8LMekEy20)

[image: cord in bag]

[image: cord in bag with label]

Comment: I do this with power transformers for various devices when not using them.  However, use a 3x5 card for the label and drop it in the bag.  Less chance of loosing it.

Comment: @BPugh You don't lose a good gaffa!